# How to correctly use try catch in integer overflow?

Tags: try-catch, overflow

```
int Product(int x, int y){
   try{
      num = x * y;
    }catch(std::overflow_error and e){}
   return num;
}
```

//I am new to try catch and would like to know how to return the product of two numbers, but also throw //this overflow error if the inputs reach over the max for integers

Comment: what language are you trying to use? this looks similar to c++

Comment: Yes, this is C++